# Error in Python IRC bot

Tags: python, bots, irc

I was making a simple python IRC bot for a channel in freenode, just for fun. It was working all right with the following code for connecting to the server:

```
irc.connect((server,6667))
irc.send("USER "+botnick+" "+botnick+" "+botnick+" :Howdy mate!\n")
irc.send("NICK "+botnick+"\n")
irc.send("PRIVMSG nickserv :iNOOPE\r\n") #I don't know what this does
irc.send("JOIN "+channel+"\n")
```

(Sub-question: What does that 4th line do? )

But the while loop was triggering only when **irc.recv(2040)** was returning something. So I followed online examples and added a

```
irc.setblocking(False)
```

after

```
irc.connect((server,6667))
```

and a

```
time.sleep(1)
```

at the beginning of the while loop.

So now the connecting part looked like this:

```
irc.connect((server,6667))
irc.setblocking(False)
irc.send("USER "+botnick+" "+botnick+" "+botnick+" :Howdy mate!\n")
irc.send("NICK "+botnick+"\n")
irc.send("PRIVMSG nickserv :iNOOPE\r\n")
irc.send("JOIN "+channel+"\n")
```

But now when I try to run the program, it shows an error:

```
irc.send("USER "+botnick+" "+botnick+" "+botnick+" :Howdy mate!\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I can't solve this error and it disappears when I remove **irc.setblocking(False)**. But I really need the loop to execute regardless of **irc.recv(2040)** returning something or not...So can anyone figure out the error?

EDIT: The error above showed up when I ran this in the python shell (Because CMD was closing too quickly for me to read the error). Now I managed to record and view the error in CMD, and it says:

```
text=irc.recv(2040)
A non blocking socket operation could not be completed immediatly.
```

Help?

Comment: [Nickserv](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/1940) is a service for keeping your nick across sessions. You operate it by talking to it. `NOOPE` sounds very much like it does nothing at all, but consult your own nickserv's documentation for details about its command set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself. The **text=irc.recv(2040)** was the issue. I put it in a **try...except** block and it solved the problem.